# Cómo puedo hacer para que thymeleaf no trate de renderizarse en las diferentes peticiones

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, thymeleaf

Tengo un rest api en Java, solo tengo dos clases que manejan las rutas:
[image: Estructura de los manejadores de las rutas]

El archivo `ViewsRoutes` Es el que va a tener las rutas a cada una de las vistas, es el archivo que quiero que se encargue de renderizar los templates de thymeleaf

El archivo `ContactMeFormRoutes`, o, mejor dicho, las clases dentro del paquete `api` se van a encargar de resolver las peticiones que no vayan a devolver una vista, no quiero que estas me rendericen un documento de thymeleaf

El contenido de la clase ViewsRoutes es el siguiente:

```java
@Controller
public class ViewsRoutes {
    @Autowired
    private ViewsControllers controller;

@RequestMapping("/")
    public String home(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Model model) {return controller.home(request, response, model);}
}
```

En este caso, controller me devuelve el string del nombre de la plantilla que voy a renderizar. esta clase funciona excelente, hace lo que tiene que hacer.

El contenido de la clase ContactMeFotmRoutes es el siguiente

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api/contactmeform")
public class ContactMeFormRoutes {
    @Autowired
    private ContactMeFormControllers controller;

    @PostMapping
    public String addRequest(@RequestBody SolicitudEntity contactRequestEntity) {return controller.addRequest(contactRequestEntity);}

    @GetMapping("/all")
    public List<SolicitudEntity> getAll() {return controller.getAll();}
}
```

La clase anterior también hace lo que tiene que hacer, Pero a continuación viene el detalle del problema: Por ejemplo, la función `addRequest` llama al controlador y devuelve un string "json" de acuerdo a si la petición fue satisfactoria o no, en caso de que no devuelve `"{'ok': 0}"`, en caso contrario la respuesta es: `"{'ok': 1}"`. entonces me sale en siguiente error: `Error resolving template [{'ok': 0}]`.
Spring trata de renderizar un template con el nombre "{'ok': 0}" el cual no existe

Estoy usando Java 17, Java y kotlin, tymeleaf

```xml
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
<version>2.7.3</version>
```

¿Hay alguna forma de evitar esto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

después de seguir intentando pude resolver mi propia duda, y era más sencillo de lo que podría pensar.

El problama era la anotación `@Controller`, ya que esta es la que se usa cuando se va a usar el gestor de plantillas, en lugar de la anotación **@Controller** se debe color la anotación `@RestController`

Entonces el Código de **ContactMeFormRoutes** quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/contactmeform")
public class ContactMeFormRoutes {
    @Autowired
    private ContactMeFormControllers controller;

    @PostMapping
    public String addRequest(@RequestBody SolicitudEntity contactRequestEntity) {return controller.addRequest(contactRequestEntity);}

    @GetMapping("/all")
    public List<SolicitudEntity> getAll() {return controller.getAll();}
}
```

Con mucho gusto